# UIKit custom table view header not working

Tags: swift, uikit

Here is my code for a custom header view for a table, but for some reason the header view does not display either the label or the button, and it doesn't make sense to me. I tested it by changing the background color and I verified it shows up but it does not display the button or label still. It seems .addSubView() isn't working?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) ->.   UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView() // ignored frame for now
    let title = UILabel()
    title.text = "title"
    let clear = UIButton() // ignored frame for now
    clear.setTitle("clear", for: .normal) // change to "Clear" title later
    clear.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    clear.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    headerView.addSubview(title)
    headerView.addSubview(clear)
    return headerView
}
```

Comment: Because your label and your button doesn't have their own shape, you should add some constrain for both your label and button attach to your headerView.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be like this:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let clearButton = UIButton()
    headerView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    headerView.addSubview(clearButton)

    clearButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    clearButton.backgroundColor = .orange

    titleLabel.text = "Title"
    clearButton.setTitle("Clear", for: .normal)

    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    clearButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0),
      titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerYAnchor),
  
      clearButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  headerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10.0),
      clearButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerYAnchor),
      clearButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),
      clearButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0)
    ])

  return headerView
}
```

Try adding constrain of your label and button attach to your headerView. It'll show result like below: 
[image]

I hope this can help your problem, cheer.